# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Trying to bind my data to the view model to display but i am getting this error message in my console:

> **Uncaught Exception (js): Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

for this line: `bindModel(data);`

```
 var getList = function () {
            Ajax.Get({
                Url: ...,
                DataToSubmit: {id: properties.Id },
                DataType: "json",
                OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                    bindModel(data);

                }
            });
        };


    // Binds the main ViewModel
        var bindModel = function (data) {
            var _self = viewModel;

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#ListView')[0]);
        };

    var viewModel = {
            ListRoleTypes: ko.observableArray([]),
            .....
        };
```

Comment: exactly what it means - where did you define data? `OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                    bindModel(data);

                }`

Comment: i don't know knockout.. but try changing `bindModel(data);` to `bindModel(roleData);` or changing `OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR)` to `OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR)`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ wow i can't believe that i overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: NP :)  It's easy for me to spot but I've been in your shoes before.   Always have to pay attention to the exception that is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `bindModel(data);` to `bindModel(roleData);` and it will work. It's just a variable name error